# identify words closing with the a particular character

Tags: python

I have a list of words as follows:

```
apple
grapes
pappu
pop
seeds
```

I want to identify and display all the words that is ending with the character `u` and `p`.
The expected output is as follows:

```
pappu
pop
```

my code which is incorrect:

```
p = [w for w in theWord if re.search('(u|p)$', w)]
print p
```

Comment: Your regex should work. What does `theWord` actually look like?

Comment: Most likely it's read from a file and ends with `\n`.

Comment: @limelights regex automatically ignores newline.

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary i had no idea, thanks! :)

Answer (score 4):

Use `str.endswith`, `regex` is not needed here.

```
p = [w for w in theWord if w.endswith(('p','u'))]
```

Demo:

```
>>> theWord = ['apple', 'grapes', 'pappu', 'pop', 'seeds']
>>> p = [w for w in theWord if w.endswith(('p','u'))]
for w in p:
     print w
...     
pappu
pop
```

BTW your code is okay, you just need a for-loop to get your expected output:

```
>>> p = [w for w in theWord if re.search('(u|p)$', w)]
>>> for w in p:
...     print w
...     
pappu
pop
```

Answer (score 1):

you could do this:

```
words = ['apple','grapes','pappu','pop','seeds','']

for word in words:
    if word[-1:] == 'p' or word[-1:]== 'u':
         print word
```

and index the last letter of each word and if they match the staement then do whatever with them

Comment: What if the list contains an empty string?

Comment: fixed it but your solution is probably better and shorter

Comment: @just Just `if word` is enough, and it's better to use slicing: `word[-1:] == 'p'`

Comment: No need of `if word != '':` now, slices don't raise `IndexError`.

Comment: Thanks for correcting all my mistakes Ashwini, im still learning :)

Answer (score 0):

You can always use slicing, reverse indexing:

```
>>> theWord = ['apple', 'grapes', 'pappu', 'pop', 'seeds']
>>> [w for w in theWord if w[-1].lower() in ['p', 'u']]
['pappu', 'pop']
>>>
```

*N.B. The `.lower()` is only needed if you would like to get words that end in P and U as well*

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17905563/identify-words-closing-with-the-a-particular-character/17905567#comment26155172_17905584